# Auth.json module recuperation

Tags: magento2, auth.json

I have my sandbox env and production env working with the same auth.json.

For some reason When we tried to push a feature in prod today, the archive was unable to be found (404).

But the credentials from auth.json is 100% fine as it works on the sandbox env.

I'm wondering if the module hasn't change his location or name.

But when i try to hit it in a simple get query in the navigator it's asking obviously for the authentification...ignoring the fact that i'm connected or not to the magento account.

https://repo.magento.com/archives/netreviews/avisverifies/netreviews-avisverifies-3.9.4.0.zip

Do I have a way to try to access these achives folder to see what's in there ? Without getting

> You haven't provided your Magento authentication keys. For instructions, visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Answer (score 0):

repo.magento.com uses http-basic auth. In the past I have been able to download the zip files by copying the full URL from my composer.lock file and putting `public_key:private_key@` between the `https://` and the rest of the URL when trying to open it in Chrome. Today I can't seem to get it to work for anything but the json files.

Is is possible the keys being used are different between the environments? Composer will take auth details from a number of places including:

- Global `auth.json`,
- Project/Repo `auth.json`,
- Auth creds stored in `composer.json`,
- `COMPOSER_AUTH` environment variable.

To verify they are using the same details you can run the command `composer show vendorname/packagename --all -vvv`

The `-vvv` makes composer output verbose debug data for example, every time it downloads a file:

```
Downloading https://repo.magento.com/p/magento/project-community-edition%24some_hash.json

[200] https://repo.magento.com/p/magento/project-community-edition%24some_hash.json
```

When it loads a config file:

```
Loading config file /Users/myUser/.composer/auth.json
```

Very usefully it also does this when it has decided on which auth details to use:

```
Using HTTP basic authentication with username "my_magento_account_public_key"
```

This debug data should allow you to identify the issue.